# Windows Vista - How to add/remove security for folder structure via command prompt

Tags: windows, windows-vista, security

In Windows Vista, I'm looking to remove a user group from having access to a set of folders.  I'm trying to remove the group from the folders completely.  I'm wondering how I would do this in a command prompt.

In the GUI you would do this by right clicking on a folder, selecting Properties and then navigating to the security tab and selecting "Remove" on a security group.

Comment: you can use icacls

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command you want is:

> CACLS C:\directory /E /R /T /C
>   "GroupName"

Do CACLS /? at a command prompt for the switch usage details, or Google "CACLS examples" (without the quotes).

Comment: Note:  I used ICACLS since CACLS is depreciated in Vista.